# How do I flatten the results of an aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query...

```
db.getCollection('apprenticeships')
.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            'Vacancy._id': { $in: [1, 2, 3] },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: { 
            '_id': {
                'VacancyId': '$Vacancy._id',
                'Status': '$Status'
            },
            'Count': { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            '_id.VacancyId': 1,
            '_id.Status': 1
        }
    }
])
```

Which gives results where each element has following structure

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "VacancyId" : 1,
        "Status" : 90
    },
    "Count" : 40.0
}
```

How can I remap that structure so that the elements in the output look like this instead?

```
{
  "VacancyId": 1,
  "Status": 90,
  "Count": 40
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to aggregation pipeline to add new fields `VacancyId` and `status` and then hide the `_id`

```js
db.getCollection('apprenticeships')
    .aggregate([{
            $match: {
                'Vacancy._id': {
                    $in: [1, 2, 3]
                },
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                '_id': {
                    'VacancyId': '$Vacancy._id',
                    'Status': '$Status'
                },
                'Count': {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                '_id.VacancyId': 1,
                '_id.Status': 1
            }
        },
        {
             
            {
                $project:{ 'VacancyId': '$_id.VacancyId', 'Status': '$_id.Status', 'Count': '$Count', '_id': 0 }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: $addFields was not recognised. However, I added `{ $project:{ 'VacancyId': '$_id.VacancyId', 'Status': '$_id.Status', 'Count': '$Count', '_id': 0 }` and it worked. If you update your answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need ``_id: 0`` for projections in aggregations.

Comment: @Derick Without it the _id field remained in the result elements.